# Java Calendar, getting current month value, clarification needed

Tags: java, calendar

On November 1st ..

```
  Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH); // prints 10 (October)
```

It would make sense if we start with 0, but it appears that we do not

```
  Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.JANUARY); // prints 1
```

What am i missing please?

Comment: `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.JANUARY);` is the same of `Calendar.getInstance().get(0);` which is the same of `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.ERA);`... resulting in 1.

Comment: Months ARE 0-based. Your first call is correct to get the current month (November).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Months in Java Calendar *are* 0-indexed. `Calendar.JANUARY` isn't a **field** so you shouldn't be passing it in to the `get` method.

Comment: How would you get current month please?

Comment: The way you're doing it is correct Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) . Months are just 0-indexed so if you wanted to display it, you'd want to add 1.

Answer (score 15):

as others said Calendar.MONTH returns int and is zero indexed.

to get the current month as a `String` use `SimpleDateFormat.format()` method

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(cal.getTime()));

returns NOV
```

Answer (score 14):

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

is zero based, 10 is November. From the javadoc;

> public static final int MONTH
>   Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a
>   calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian
>   and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the
>   number of months in a year.

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.JANUARY);
```

is not a sensible thing to do, the value for `JANUARY` is 0, which is the same as `ERA`, you are effectively calling;

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.ERA);
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1` to get current month.

Comment: Upvoting.
The explanation is that in the java Calendar class month is:

    return month as int, January is 0, December is 11.

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.util.*;

class GetCurrentmonth
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int month;
        GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();      
        month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        month = month+1;
        System.out.println("Current month is  " + month);
    }
}
```

Comment: here following code will give you your current system month

Answer (score 3):

`Calendar.get` takes as argument one of the standard Calendar fields, like `YEAR` or `MONTH` not a month name.

`Calendar.JANUARY` is 0, which is also the value of `Calendar.ERA`, so `Calendar.getInstance().get(0)` will return the era, in this case `Calendar.AD`, which is 1.

For the first part of your question, note that, as is wildly documented, months start at 0, so 10 is actually November.